# Xcode 4 why do I see XML when clicking on MainStoryBoard.storyboard: seems like a bug

Tags: ios, xcode

In an Xcode project, I see XML when clicking on MainStoryBoard.storyboard instead of the graphical design, why and how to restore the right view ?

Update: I think it's a bug of XCode 4.2 because on another project, when I click on version editor I have XML but when I click on standard editor it shows visual design.

Is there a way to fix this and not to force me to recreate my visual design by hand once again ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To fix the issue, right-click MainStoryboard.storyboard, then choose "Open as >" and then "Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard".

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you are not using the source control editor, which shows you the changes for a given file. You can change this in the Toolbar at the top right.

Check this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129225356/http://beginning-mac-programming.timisted.net:80/xcode-4-general-overview.html) in the section "Editor"

[image: version-editor]

Comment: There are 3 icons in Editor bar: I tried standard editor and assistant editor but still have xml. Is it what you mean ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Update: I think it's a bug of XCode 4.2 because on another project, when I click on version editor I have XML but when I click on standard editor it shows visual design.

Is there a way to fix this and not to force me to recreate my visual design by hand once again ?

Comment: yes that's the one I meant. what you can do is to add a new storyboard via "File > New File" with another name and then insert the xml content of your current storyboard, then in project settings set this new storyboard as the initial storyboard.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me using xcode 6
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this issue, but it was a bit different.  I had a merge issue with Git on my storyboard, so I had to manually edit the XML to resolve the conflict.  After this, there was no 'Interface Builder-iOS Storyboard' option available in the "Open as" menu so I couldn't change it back to the visual editor.  To fix this I simply restarted XCode and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

After using SeanK's solution (restart XCode) I still manually needed to right-click the storyboard and choose Open as > Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than just one storyboard go back and forth - click different one, go back to the one you want to display as an iOS storyboard. It's not XML any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension like this "your_storyboard.storyboard" then right-click MainStoryboard.storyboard, then choose "Open as >" and then "Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard".